# Отключение/включение триггера в процедуре

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql

Пишу участок кода, в котором для работы на время операции необходимо отключить триггер, а затем - включить.
На самую первую строку "alter table..." выдаётся ошибка:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:

Версия - 9i.

Как включить/отключить триггер?

```
 if p_DicPurpose = 1 and p_RegisteredStandart = 1 then
   alter trigger TIB_j_standart_reg_name disable; -- отключаем триггер генерации наименования зарегистрированного эталона

   insert into j_standart_reg                     -- для предотвращения возникновения ошибки
    (equ_id)
   values
    (l_NewEquipmentId);
   alter trigger TIB_j_standart_reg_name enable;
 end if;
```

Comment: На вопрос уже ниже ответили. от себя замечу, что так делать вообще не стоит. DDL завершит текущую транзакцию и откат выполняемого в данном pl/sql блоке и до него будет невозможен. И что самое печальное - это почти равносильно тому, что вы просто удалите триггер навсегда. в момент между disable и enable другой процесс может сделать в таблице, что то на что нужна реакция, а триггер выполнен не будет. стоит рассмотреть другие пути обхода, например модифицировать некое поле и/или использовать специальное значение на которое среагирует триггер и не будет выполнять то, что не надо

Comment: @Mike отличный комментарий! Если добавить в него пример реализации без DDL и ссылки на документацию, то получится отличный ответ, который дополнит уже существующий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PL\SQL блоках операторы DDL надо обернуть в `execute immediate`

```
execute immediate 'alter trigger TIB_j_standart_reg_name disable';
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 3):

Несколько подзабытое решение появившееся до [`execute immediate`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317). Это пакетная процедура [`dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement (ddl_statement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73238). Оба решения делают то же самое, в PL/SQL контексте выполняет DDL, который не поддерживается статическими инструкциями. Предпочтительней использовать `execute immediate`.

Но небольшое преимущество у `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement` всё же есть - её можно выполнить в дистрибутивной среде. Например отключить триггеры в удалённой базе до того, как произвести вставку или изменение в таблице в этой же удалённой базе.

Пример:

```
create database link loopback using 'oracl'; 
Database link LOOPBACK created.

begin
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@loopback('create table t1 (id number)');
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@loopback('create trigger on_t1_new before insert on t1 for each row begin null; end;');
end;    
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare ret number; begin     
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@loopback('alter trigger on_t1_new disable');
    insert into t1@loopback values (99);
    select id into ret from t1@loopback;      
    dbms_output.put_line ('ret@loopback='||ret);
    commit;
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@loopback('alter trigger on_t1_new enable');
end;
/ 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ret@loopback=99
```

Внимательно ознакомьтесь с комментарием от [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720237/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5/760718#comment1084497_720237) перед тем, как решите использовать предложенное решение.